# In Emacs, how can I paste into multi-term

Tags: emacs

When using multi-term to run a terminal within emacs, I would like to be able to paste a command into the multi-term window, and then run it.  Currently, when I do so, the pasted item does appear in the multi-term input window, however, if I hit enter, the command is ignored. It also doesn't show up in the terminal's history.  For example, I'm pasting

echo "hello"

It looks like it worked--I see the text following the prompt.  But when I hit enter it doesn't execute. I'm using multi-term:  http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/MultiTerm

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The default function `yank` doesn't work with `multi-term` or more
precisely with `term-mode` because the yank isn't « really » inserted.
To paste, you've to use the function `term-paste` which is bound to
<kbd>S-insert</kbd> by default. Of course, you can bind <kbd>C-y</kbd>
to use it in `term-mode`

```
(add-hook 'term-mode-hook (lambda ()
                            (define-key term-raw-map (kbd "C-y") 'term-paste)))
```

Comment: I added this to my .emacs, but no joy.

Comment: @ebeland: I've tried it with `-q` and it works, thus something must be wrong with your configuration. To try it: `emacs -q` then switch to the `*scratch*` buffer and paste (or write) the previous snippet in and evaluate it (with `C-x C-e` or `M-x eval-buffer RET`) then load `multi-term.el` and start a new term with `M-x multi-term`.

Comment: I'll give it a shot on Monday when I get in. Thanks for the help!

Comment: The key piece of info here I needed was `term-raw-map` *not* `term-mode-map`.

Answer (score 10):

In term-mode (which multi-term uses) there are two input modes:

- line mode
- char mode

You can switch to line mode with <kbd>C-c</kbd><kbd>C-j</kbd> then
yank the text, switch back to char mode <kbd>C-c</kbd><kbd>C-k</kbd>
and run the command. I think of char-mode as the input mode that works
like you would expect terminal input to work. For example, if you type
something on the command line and cut it with <kbd>C-x</kbd>, then
<kbd>C-y</kbd> will paste what you cut from the command line. I think
of line-mode as the input mode that you would expect from a text
buffer in emacs.

For details about the two input modes check
[this page](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Term-Mode.html#Term-Mode)